# Balance too low to burn | Reason

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am running an Ethereum burning script on arbitrum. I got this error mostly. Meanwhile, The script is required to burn the whole balance.

```
Balance too low to burn (balance=0.00024506291612428 gasPrice=0.49) gwei
```

My function:

```
 const gasPrice = balance.div(500000);
    if (gasPrice.lt(1e9)) {
        console.log(`Balance too low to burn (balance=${formatEther(balance)} gasPrice=${gasPriceToGwei(gasPrice)}) gwei`);
        return;
    }
    const leftovers = balance.sub(gasPrice.mul(500000));
    console.log(`Leftovers: ${formatEther(leftovers)} ETH`);

    try {
        console.log(`Burning ${formatEther(balance)}`);
        const nonce = await burnWallet.provider.getTransactionCount(burnWallet.address);
        const tx = await burnWallet.sendTransaction({
            to: flashbotsBeerFund,
            gasLimit: 500000,
            gasPrice,
            nonce,
            value: leftovers,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It mean that your wallet doesnt have enough Coin to pay gas fee to execute the transaction.

Hence the error is Coming